# Argparse argument generated help, 'metavar' with choices

Tags: python, argparse

When using an argument (optional and positional both have this *problem*) with the keyword `choices`, the generated help output shows those choices.

If that same argument also includes a `metavar` keyword, the list of choices is omitted from the generated output.

What I had in mind, was to show the `metavar` in the `usage` line, but actually show the available choices when the 'autohelp' lists positional/optional argument details.

Any simple fixes/workarounds?

---

I have already started an argparse wrapper for custom help functionality. Perhaps this should be another feature on my TODO list.

Comment: Yes, subclassing the HelpFormatter is the 'approved' way of altering the help format.  The provided examples do simple things like changing how text is wrapped.  Without digging into the code I can't say whether your change would be trivial or complex.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can add the choices to the help text.

```
parser=argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-f',metavar="TEST",choices=('a','b','c'),
    help='choices, {%(choices)s}')
print parser.format_help()
```

produces:

```
usage: stack20328931.py [-h] [-f TEST]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
  -f TEST     choices, {a, b, c}
```

Comment: This definitely qualifies for simple fix. Thanks much.