# Argparse to have type as choice

Tags: python, python-2.7, argparse, optparse

I have some old code which has optparse as their argument library. It has type as choice as one of the arguments

```
type = "choice"
```

I am trying to convert my code to have argparse. What should I put in the type? If I add type = choice it throws an error:

```
NameError: global name 'choice' is not defined
```

What should be the value of type here if I am using argparse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `optparse`, `choice` type is just a special form of `string`. From the [`optparse` documenattion](https://docs.python.org/2/library/optparse.html#standard-option-types):

> `"choice"` options are a subtype of `"string"` options. The `choices` option attribute (a sequence of strings) defines the set of allowed option arguments.

You don't need to specify this as a type in `argparse`; all you need to provide is the choices. Remove the `type` argument altogether, or set it `str` if you want to be explicit.

Also see the [*choices* documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#choices) for `argparse`; this is a lot more flexible than in `optparse` as this also allows for the choices to be of a type other than strings.

Comment: But when I add str or remove type the moment I run my code say like this: python try1.py --help then it prints the help information specific to that argument along with the choices as well. When I was working with optparse I didn't face such an issue, I used to get only the help information specific to that argument.

Comment: @wannaC: I am not certain what you are asking here. `argparse` works differently, it will never produce the exact same output.

Comment: @wannaC: and that also sounds like a *different* question; your problem with the `type` argument has been solved, has it not?

Comment: The `metavar` parameter replaces the `choices` list in the help display.

Comment: @hpaulj: right, which has a [simple fix](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20328931/argparse-argument-generated-help-metavar-with-choices).

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Yes that answers my question. Thanks for the above link.